# Easy & safe way to recompile elementary kernel?

Tags: release-freya, kernel

(I edited this question to make it more useful for everyone)

In order to make the keyboard of my Medion P2213T work I have to recompile the elementary kernel with just a very small adjustment, namely changing the value `HID_MAX_USAGES` to `65536` in `include/linux/hid.h`.

I tried a [tutorial](https://vuanhduy.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/recompiling-kernel-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/) for Ubuntu 14.04, I ended up with a working keyboard, but the new kernel had horrible performance even on the desktop...

So my question, is there an easy tutorial to recompile the kernel, known to work with the latest version of elementary OS freya?

Answer (score 7):

The kernel should be identical to the Ubuntu 14.04's kernel. elementary is [built on on Ubuntu Minimal](http://blog.elementary.io/post/120736900431/how-much-of-elementary-os-is-just-ubuntu-gnome), so an Ubuntu tutorial should work just fine.

That said, a [new version of the kernel](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-14.04.3) is coming to Ubuntu 14.04 this month.
That upgrade expands hardware support, so it might fix your problem!

Comment: You can already install the new kernel with 
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-vivid

Comment: @JohnGuerreiro that's not the point, elementary wants to compile a kernel with special adjustments.

Comment: @Rafael I understand, that's why I didn't add it as an answer, it was merely an addition to Ryan's answer "That said, a new version of the kernel is coming to Ubuntu 14.04 this month. That upgrade expands hardware support, so it might fix your problem!"

Comment: @JohnGuerreiro Careful, it's not quite that simple. There aren't currently the matching graphics stacks for that, which can cause serious issues in some circumstances.

Comment: @Lewis Goddard there aren't? Been using xserver-xorg-lts-vivid for a week, unless I'm getting confused, in that case please correct me.

Comment: Well, is there a hint it will be working with the new kernel out of the box? I had a very simular issue with ubuntu 12.04 and an old sharkoon mouse (also had to change HID_MAX_USAGES) and indeed it was fixed in the 14.04 kernel!

Comment: I now tried to follow this tutorial: https://vuanhduy.wordpress.com/2014/05/03/recompiling-kernel-for-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr/ it all works fine until it comes to parsing the option file (make oldconfig), it then asks me a bunch of questions I can't answer, I guess there are some new options not included in my old config file? That would mean those are not the same kernel versions, right? Not sure though... Could some one post a link to a tutorial that works for elementary for sure?

Comment: Questions like this one: Network priority cgroup (NETPRIO_CGROUP) [N/m/y/?] (NEW) 
I think if it was the same version it should not happen right?

Comment: Also I now tried installing the kernel like recommended in the first comment, but the problem still persists.

Comment: What happens if you accept the default for each prompt? Does the build succeed, or do you get an error?

Comment: @JohnGuerreiro My mistake, they were released _super_ recently. We were having serious troubles because of it a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Alright, it worked! I was not sure if there is default, it did not show any of the options (N/m/y/?) behind the line when I just hit enter. There were around 20-30 of those options without value. I still have to choose the kernel in grub manually, but thats not a big deal. For the record: I followed the tutorial I mentioned step by step, but after "cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config" I ran "scratch-text-editor include/linux/hid.h" and changed "HID_MAX_USAGES" to 65536.

Comment: One small bug now: for some reason the keyboard has english layout on login screen, strangely the usb keyboard has german layout... I will try around a bit, if it does not work I will create a new question. Thanks everybody! :-)

Comment: Hi, sorry I had to mark the answer as unsolved again. While the keyboard worked, I had huge performance issues with the new kernel, booting with the old kernel made everything work well again. I tried it out with several games in steam, not even the smallest 2D-games worked with the new kernel... I will clearify the question as well, so it is less device specific.

Comment: You might have better luck submitting a new question about the performance issue. To me, that seems separate from the "how do I compile a custom kernel" question. I wonder whether it's related to the problem that folks have reported with graphics stacks in the latest kernel.

Comment: Video performance problems with the new kernel might be related to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346/+bug/1465706

Comment: I actually ended up with an older version as well, not really what I wanted... There are actually quite a lot devices with this issue: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51491